# Page not found (404) (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I got an `error` message while clicking `[Delete]` option/link in `post_detail.html`:

```
Page not found (404)
No comment found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/7/comment/delete/
Raised by:  blog.views.CommentDeleteView
```

Here is my files:

`post_detail.html` file

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    {% if not post.comments.all %}
      No Comments Yet... 
      <a href="{% url 'post-comment' post.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
    
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

    {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'post-comment' post.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
      <br/><br/>

      {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <strong>
          {{user}},
        </strong>
        <small>
          {{comment.date_added}}
        </small>
        <br/>

        {{comment.body}}
        <br/>
        {% if request.user == user %}
          <a href="{% url 'comment-delete' post.pk %}">[Delete]</a>
          
        {% endif %}
        
        <br/><br/>

      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    
{% endblock content %}
```

`models.py` file

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls.base import reverse_lazy
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Comment(models.Model): 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80) 
    email = models.EmailField() 
    body = models.TextField() 
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
```

`views.py` file

```
from django.contrib.messages.api import success
from django.urls.base import reverse_lazy
from users.forms import CommentForm
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post, Comment
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


class AddCommentView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'blog/add_comment.html'
    
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk'] 
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse_lazy('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': pk})

class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'blog/comment_delete.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse_lazy('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': pk})

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user == comment.author
```

`comment_delete.html` file

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Delete Post</legend>
                <h2>Are you sure you want to delete the post comment</h2>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'post-detail' object.id %}">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

`urls.py` file

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    AddCommentView,
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    CommentDeleteView,
    
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/delete/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', AddCommentView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

Comment: `reverse_lazy('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': pk})` -- after deleting, you are redirecting to the same deleted pk?

Comment: @bdbd But if `[Delete]` link isn't working,  how 'pk' is deleted?

Comment: I think what happens is, it deletes the object successfully, then redirects to the post-detail with the pk you just deleted, but that object is already gone hence the 404